# Hibernate exception when starting Tomcat (after upgrade to hibernate-3.5.0)

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, annotations, upgrade

I'm getting the following exception when starting a Tomcat instance with my web app after upgrading to Hibernate 3.5.0:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Fail to process type argument in a generic declaration. Type: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.getClassFromGenericArgument(AttributeFactory.java:836)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.getClassFromGenericArgument(AttributeFactory.java:833)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:748)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:723)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:518)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:93)
```

As this happens on Tomcat startup, I have no idea where to look in my code to prevent that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting that error message into google would have shown you any number of explanations, including this JIRA issue:

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5098